# How to check page url with Selenide

Tags: selenide

How to check page url in selenide ?

For example I should check if url() is [www.google.pl](http://www.google.pl)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Selenide support checking urls from version 5.23.0. Enjoy

````
import static com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverConditions.*;

webdriver().shouldHave(url("https://auth.google.com"));
webdriver().shouldHave(url("https://mastercard.ee"), Duration.ofSeconds(42));
webdriver().shouldNotHave(url("http://yandex.ru");
webdriver().shouldNotHave(urlStartingWith("ftp://"));
webdriver().shouldHave(currentFrameUrl(baseUrl + "/login.html"));
webdriver().shouldHave(currentFrameUrlStartingWith(baseUrl + "/logout.html"));```
````

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `browser address url`. This is how to get `current url` by `Selenide`:

```
String currentUrl = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl();
```

Solution example with `junit4` `assertEquals()` method:

```
String url = "http://www.google.pl";
Selenide.open(url);
String currentUrl = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl();
assertEquals(url, currentUrl);
```

with `junit4` & `Selenide` imports:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide;
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Tested. Results:
[image]